# iAd shows white box

Tags: ios7, iad

I have a little problem with `iAd`. Sometimes it shows a blank white box. When I try it with `Admob` it works perfect. Sometimes the banner comes correctly from the button but sometimes it shows the white box immediately. What is the issue?

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        if (self.view.frame.size.height != self.iAdBannerView.frame.origin.y)
                    {
            self.iAdBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.iAdBannerView.frame.size.width, self.iAdBannerView.frame.size.height);
                                    iAdBannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers= [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,nil];
                        iAdBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
                    }

            if (self.view.frame.size.height != self.gAdBannerView.frame.origin.y)
            {
                self.gAdBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(150, self.view.frame.size.height, self.gAdBannerView.frame.size.width, self.gAdBannerView.frame.size.height);
            }

// Hide the banner by sliding down
-(void)hideBanner:(UIView*)banner
{
    if (banner && ![banner isHidden])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideBanner" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        banner.hidden = TRUE;
    }
}

// Show the banner by sliding up
-(void)showBanner:(UIView*)banner
{
    if (banner && [banner isHidden])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"showBanner" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        banner.hidden = FALSE;
    }
}

#pragma mark - ADBanner delegate methods -

// Called before the add is shown, time to move the view
- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"iAd load");
    [self hideBanner:self.gAdBannerView];
    [self showBanner:self.iAdBannerView];
}

// Called when an error occured
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"iAd error: %@", error);
    [self hideBanner:self.iAdBannerView];
    [self.gAdBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iAds doesn't always load an ad. There's a delegate method to let you know when an ad loads successfully.

[ADBannerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/ADBannerViewDelegate) has `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` and `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`.

Comment: i added the Delegate ahead

Comment: Are the delegate methods being called? Is it different between when the ad shows correctly and when it doesn't?

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103315/iad-banner-not-working) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312196/iads-sometime-appearing-as-white-boxes-in-app)?

Comment: when it works correctly the banner slides from the bottom and when it does´t work correctly a have a white box at the bottom and some seconds later it fills it with the iAd test Text. The other solution doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I think what's happening is you're getting neither an ad nor a failure, hence you see nothing. You need to have something in that space when the banner is hidden, and initialize it in that state.